# Obtaining a Schengen visa without employer No Objection Certificate (NOC)

Tags: schengen-visas

My 47 year old friend who is employed with a reputed organization has a weird problem. Her office HR does not easily give NOC for foreign travel. She is a pretty senior personality in her organization and has a travelled to Asian countries and Russia but never to Europe.

Can she attach a letter explaining her intent to return? She will also be submitting her 3 year tax return, bank account statements and an invitation letter from her niece who is living in Germany. Will this be sufficient to obtain a tourist visa? She is also buying return tickets. In short ever other document can be provided except for no objection certificate from her employer. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: The consulate is looking for strong ties to home nation when evaluating a visa application. An employer NOC demonstrates that the applicant has a job in home country. Your friend writing a letter (or someone else writing it for her) will not demonstrate anything and hence is not useful. Is the HR only averse to issuing NOCs (written letters) or do they not approve of employees going to foreign holidays at all?

Comment: I assume NOC only since she as well as her colleagues have travelled to countries which do require visas. I also do not understand the aversion. Hence asking if there is a way.

Comment: German visa application requires employed applicants to furnish a "leave letter" i.e. a record of having a sanctioned leave for the duration of their trip. As far as I am aware, it can simply be the leave sanction form or even a confirmation mail from management that the leave has been sanctioned. Can your friend manage that? You may also want to tell us your friend's nationality because document requirement depends on the processing consulate too.

Comment: Hi new user!   It's very hard to help without knowing the countries involved.

Comment: Oh sorry. Forgot to mention she is from India. And she is single. Have residential property.

Answer (score 3):

I just got a Schengen visa 'C' today from Austrian embassy in Washington DC and while applying a few days back, I was asked for a recent proof of employment. There was never an emphasis on a NOC.

I was specifically asked the employment contract to begin with but then since that was dated and signed in 2016, I was asked for a more recent proof. Luckily I had the NOC but at no point was the word NOC ever used and they only wanted a proof of employment and probably a proof of sanctioned leaves.

This is just an experience and having a NOC is always recommended.